# Django on creating new model store records of existing user and its data

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have created a model Customer:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_index=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, db_index=True)
    phone = models.IntegerFeild(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

as well as a new model called XYZ:

```
class XYZ(models.Model):
        customer = models.OneToOneFieldOneToOneField(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        abc = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='x')
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How should I insert data into this XYZ table for an existing Customer, without using manually `Insert` into the query? Is there any Django query or way to insert the existing customer records in the XYZ table?

Comment: You want some default values for XYZ?

Comment: @VineethSai added default value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it, As it is unclear how your data from `XYZ` is stored so I'm assuming static values.

Go into django shell. You can do this by running `python manage.py shell`

Now import your models

```
from yourapp.models import Customer, XYZ
```

Also import your `user` model

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

fetch the user object you want to add.

```
user = User.objects.get(username='your_username')
```

If you want admins you can do this

`superusers = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)` # This will get all the admins of your website. But beware this is a queryset(i.e list of user objects) if there is more than one admin for your site.

now you can create an entry for each of the customer object into your `XYZ` table.

Finally, depending on your requirement you can run this loop.

```
for customer in Customer.objects.all():
    XYZ.objects.create(customer=customer, abc="your string", user=user)
```

Comment: how you can pass request.user which is undefined?

Comment: Sorry about that, you need to import the user model too and get the specific user for that entry

Comment: I updated my customer model where now it has user coumn too

Comment: All your customer objects are available in the for loop via the `customer` variable. Get the user you want from there. and update it in the `XYZ`

Comment: what if need to add only admin user I can apply any filter over here?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should do is these steps:

1. python manage.py shell
2. query all Customer

   from path.to.your.models import Customer

   customers = Customer.objects.filter(users=
3. insert all XYZ

   for c in customers:

   ```
   if c.users.is_admin:
       xyz = XYZ(
           customer=c
           user=c.users
           )
       xyz.save()
   ```

Comment: what if need to add only admin user I can apply any filter over here?